# How to find elements inside div by tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I am trying to do this:

```
var element_current_classes=($("#form_div :textarea").attr('class'));
```

or this:

```
var element_current_classes=($("#form_div :select").attr('class'));
```

I am getting this error - **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: textarea**

It works only with 'input' and button

What I am trying to do is to find elements inside the form by their tags

Any ideas?

Comment: Please read this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

Comment: you can find list of additional selectors in sizzle (jq selector engine), there is no such selectors: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to select an html element is

```
var element_current_classes=($("#form_div textarea").attr('class'));
var element_current_classes=($("#form_div select").attr('class'));
```

**Note:** In jQuery for html tags and form elements we use name of the tag

```
$('div').hide(); // this code will hide all divs
```

Where as `:` is a selector that is use to get a specific tag or element

```
$('div:last').hide(); // this code will hide only last div
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no selector called `:textarea` or `:select` - you can use [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) to select the textarea or select element

```
$("#form_div textarea").attr('class')
$("#form_div select").attr('class')
```

The [:input pseudo selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) used to select multiple kinds of input elements like input, select, textarea etc

Answer (score 0):

```
var element_current_classes = $("#form_div select").attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `:` selector to get textarea or select . just use element selector.
try this

```
 var element_current_classes=$("#form_div select").attr('class'); //select
 var element_current_classes=$("#form_div textarea").attr('class'); //textarea
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing selectors like `:input` with HTML tag names, like `teaxtarea`.

```
$("#form_div textarea");
```

Will look for HTML tags `<textarea>` within elements with the ID HTML attribute `id="form_div"`.

Whereas:

```
$("#form_div :input");
```

Will look for all input tags, such as `<textarea>`, `<input>`, `<select>` and `<button>`, within the element with `id="form_div".

Selectors (starting with `:`) are jQuery specific. See:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/